# Copying files over network

Tags: powershell

OK so below is my little script that I have come up with that should copy files from my local drive to a remote server using a local server admin user.

```
$User = "SERVER-NAME\MyUser"
$Password = "Password"

$net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
$net.MapNetworkDrive("X:", "\\SERVER-NAME\c$\MyTestFolder\", $false, $User, $Password)
Copy-Item -Path "D:\Path\To\Copy\From" -Destination "X:\" -Recurse -Force -PassThru -Verbose
```

For some reason I am getting the following error, even though the server is reachable from my machine:

```
Exception calling "MapNetworkDrive" with "5" argument(s): "The network path was not found."
```

Comment: Why map the drive in the first place? If you are able to access the share with UNC then you use the UNC path and pass credentials to `Copy-Item`.

Comment: Try and escape the dollar sign in `c$` with a backtick.

Comment: @Fairy I tried that in a previous version of the script but when I tried to pass the credentials I got.

'The FileSystem provider supports credentials only on the New-PSDrive cmdlet.'

Comment: @Fairy The FileSystem provider supports credentials only on the New-PSDrive cmdlet. Which means you can't pass to creds to `Copy-Item`. Mapping the drive is the most common way around this, it's more common to see the `New-PSDrive` cmdlet used rather than mapping through WScript. But this method does usually work.

Comment: @BenH Wasn't really aware of that. Probably is only working for the Registry provider then?

Comment: @vonPryz I thought of it too, but it's not an escaping problem. The escaping seems to be done in the interior of the MapNetworkDrive function. Escaping the $ does not change the error message.

Comment: Dollar wont need escaping since there are no alphanumerics following it.

Comment: I don't know if this helps but I am able to copy the files using Copy-Item without specifying any credentials, however this is not what I am going for.
I need to be able to copy the files using the credentials of a local admin user.

Comment: @Matt That thought crossed my mind 10 seconds after asking, which was why I had deleted my comment.

Comment: Are you able to make a drive to the root share ... not the test folder?

Comment: @Matt No I am not able to. Btw is there a difference if there's a trailing backslash in the server path? It's just that without the trailing slash I get the "Access is denied" error. Sorry I'm not very good at posh.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that the script is able to copy files only if the folder was actually shared over the network (Folder Properties -> Sharing -> Advanced Sharing). No actual remote access to a file system (which is kinda disappointing).
Here's the simplified version of the script I ended up with:

```
$User = "SERVER-NAME\AdminUser"
$Password = "Password"

$net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
$net.MapNetworkDrive("x:", "\\SERVER-NAME\TestFolder", $false, $User, $Password)
Copy-Item -Path "D:\Path\To\Copy\From" -Destination "x:\" -Recurse -Force -PassThru
$net.RemoveNetworkDrive("x:", 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to create drive with new-psdrive, like this:

```
$userCRED = "SERVER-NAME\MyUser"
$pass="Password"


$passCRED = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pass -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userCRED, $passCRED

$DestinationExport="\\SERVER-NAME\c$\MyTestFolder"
New-PSDrive -Name X -PSProvider filesystem -Root $DestinationExport -Credential $cred

Copy-Item -Path "D:\Path\To\Copy\From" -Destination "X:\" -Recurse -Force -PassThru -Verbose

Remove-PSDrive -Name X
```